# How to use svn externals for a multi-module build in mixed branches?

Tags: svn, svn-externals

I've read http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html, but I didn't see the info I needed. It (barely) talked about propset, but not propedit, which is what I wanted. I have the v1.8 client.

Say I have the following module hierarchy in

```
root URL = https://mySvnRepo

^/projects/trunk/module1
^/projects/trunk/module2
^/projects/trunk/module3
```

Say I branched the whole projects/* tree to

```
^/projects/branches/branch1/module1
^/projects/branches/branch1/module2
^/projects/branches/branch1/module3
```

...and

```
^/projects/branches/branch2/module1
^/projects/branches/branch2/module2
^/projects/branches/branch2/module3
```

How can I use svn externals so my working copy looks like

```
/home/svn/projects/module1 from http://mySvnRepo/projects/trunk
/home/svn/projects/module2 from http://mySvnRepo/projects/branches/branch1
/home/svn/projects/module3 from http://mySvnRepo/projects/branches/branch2
```

For example.

I don't need a lecture on why I should/shouldn't do this. I just want to know how. If I shoot myself in the foot (or head) that's fine for now. I'm just trying to prove a workflow that may or may not work. Thanks!

Comment: Which of these are real folders in SVN? `projects`? `projects/module1`? Would `http://mySvnRepo/trunk` go under `projects/module1` into a folder named `projects/module1/trunk`?

Comment: Thanks, I've clarified the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the following `svn:externals` definition in a text file named `externals.txt`:

```
^/projects/trunk/module1 module1
^/projects/branches/branch1/module2 module2
^/projects/branches/branch2/module3 module3
```

In a working copy, run `svn mkdir` to create a directory named `externals` under the root of the repository. Then, run `svn propset svn:externals --file externals.txt` with the path to this new directory.

An `svn update` run from `externals` in the working copy will retrieve the external directories.

Comment: Please elaborate "...it is probably best to put the svn:externals in a new repository" You mean create https//myNewRepo/externals, then svn co https//myNewRepo/externals /home/externals, cd /home/externals, then svn propset svn:externals --file externals.txt, then svn up? (Note: I omitted the : in the URL to avoid making them a link)

Comment: How could/would/should I have set up the original repo to avoid creating a new repo for the svn:externals?

Comment: SVN has a [convention](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.maint.html#svn.branchmerge.maint.layout) where `trunk`, `branches`, and `tags` directories are grouped together at the same level of the hierarchy. No other directories should be at that level. To have both an `svn:externals` and the things an `svn:externals` point to in one repository, insert a directory between the root of `mySvnRepo` and `trunk/branches`. Perhaps `products`? Then create the `externals` directory at the same level as `products`.

Comment: I edited my original post to reflect the SVN convention. Can you please update your answer to reflect my changes? I think I understand you comment in the edit, but it'll just be cool see it in the answer so I can mark it as an answer. Thanks